What is the source of this leak?
I've just noticed there is a leak under my kitchen sink. At first I thought maybe one of the faucets was loose.  But when I look further, it looks like water is seeping out from the place where the top and bottom boards connect.
Do you see what I mean?  Is it more likely there is some sort of leak behind the sink?at enter image description here

So what seals th back edge of the sink? Does it trap water? Do you make sure it is dry?

Without opening the wall, it would be hard to tell. Water could be dripping from either supply line, or even from behind the sink, and following along a board until it leaks out.

Got a pic upward, from the bottom of the cabinet?  And above the counter?
